# Error after upgrading swagger-play2 to 1.5.0

Tags: playframework-2.0, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to upgrade swagger from 1.3 to 1.5.x in an existing Play Framework 2.4 application.

I've changed the dependencies to

```
"io.swagger" % "swagger-jaxrs" % "1.5.4" 
"io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.0"
```

and changed the imports from `com.wordnik.swagger` to `io.swagger` and added

```
play.modules.enabled += play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule
```

to application.conf.

It all compiles and runs however when I try to access the api-docs I get the following exception.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: io.swagger.models.Swagger["paths"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:199)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:683)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1387)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:1088)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:960)
at io.swagger.util.Json.pretty(Json.java:23)
at controllers.SwaggerBaseApiController.toJsonString(ApiHelpController.scala:197)
at controllers.ApiHelpController$$anonfun$getResource$1.apply(ApiHelpController.scala:89)
at controllers.ApiHelpController$$anonfun$getResource$1.apply(ApiHelpController.scala:83)
at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:408)
at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:407)
at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:533)
at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:530)
at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:493)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:741)
at play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:741)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:399)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapperLike$$anon$2.<init>(Wrappers.scala:281)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapperLike$class.iterator(Wrappers.scala:280)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JMapWrapper.iterator(Wrappers.scala:298)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.MapLike$FilteredKeys.foreach(MapLike.scala:231)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.size(TraversableOnce.scala:105)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.size(Traversable.scala:104)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper.size(Wrappers.scala:169)
at java.util.AbstractMap$1.size(AbstractMap.java:349)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:136)
at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:577)
at io.swagger.models.Swagger.getPaths(Swagger.java:266)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:654)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
        ... 32 more
[error] 12:42:04.504 swagger - api listing for path /booking not found
```

It looks like the problem is that io.swagger.models.Swagger.paths is null but should contain one entry for each @Api annotated class. How do I make the SwaggerModule properly initialize the paths?

Comment: you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: What I actually did is stop using the SwaggerModule. I now have swagger yaml files that I maintain with the swagger spec and write simple play controllers to fulfil those specs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that has worked for me was declaring dependencies to jackson 2.8.2 explicitly:

```
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.2",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.2"
```

As far as I have found out it does not work with 2.7.x and 2.6.x.